# Закрытие Toplevel закрывает и основное окно tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Как я уже описал сверху при закрытии Toplevel окна закрывается и основное.

```
from tkinter import *
def button_clicked():

  def choice_close():
    choice.quit()

#Окно Toplevel
  choice = Toplevel(main)
  choice.title("Net")
  choice.geometry("1000x500")
  choice.resizable(False, False)
  choice.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', choice_close)


def close():
    main.quit()


#Окно tk

main = Tk()
main.title("Da")
main.geometry("1100x650")
main.resizable(False, False)
main.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', close)
main["bg"] = "#F0F8FF" 
btn14 = Button(text="__________________", command=button_clicked).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно зачем переопределять действия закрытия окна через крестик на закрытие этого окна (при закрытии через крестик окно и так закрывается). А так просто поменяйте `choice.quit()` на `choice.destroy()`, тогда будет закрываться только это окно, а не приложение полностью.

Comment: В учебнике было сказано про протокол, так что я просто скопировал. 
А так огромное спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: Переопределение действия закрытия нужно только если вы например хотите изменить закрытие на другое действие (например добавить окошко с подтверждением, типа "вы действительно хотите закрыть?"), либо если нужно выполнить какие-то дополнительные действия перед закрытием (сохранение какого-то файла, например). А так окна и сами хорошо закрываются)