# StringVar не меняется с помощью функций

Tags: python, tkinter

Как описал уже выше `StringVar` не меняется.
Пробовал уже использовать `Toplevel()`, тоже не сработало

```
#Функции, которые должны менять
def choice_clicked_1():
    btn_text.set("Русский язык")
def choice_clicked_2():
    btn_text.set("Английский язык")
def choice_clicked_3():
    btn_text.set("Алгебра")
def choice_clicked_4():
    btn_text.set("Геометрия")

#Второстепеное окно
choice = Toplevel(main)
choice.title("Выбор предмета")
choice.geometry("1000x500")
choice.resizable(False, False)
choice.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', choice_close)
btn1 = Button(choice, text="Русский язык", bg="#F0F8FF", command=choice_clicked_1())
btn1.pack()
btn2 = Button(choice, text="Английский язык", bg="#F0F8FF", command=choice_clicked_2())
btn2.pack()
btn3 = Button(choice, text="Алгебра", bg="#F0F8FF", command=choice_clicked_3())
btn3.pack()
btn4 = Button(choice, text="Геометрия", bg="#F0F8FF", command=choice_clicked_4())

#Главное окно
main = Tk()
main.title("Умное Рассписание: Тест")
main.geometry("1100x650")
main.resizable(False, False)
main.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', close)
main["bg"] = "#F0F8FF"
btn14 = Button(text="__________________", textvariable=btn_text, command=button_clicked).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
#Переменная через которую происходит изменения
global btn_text
btn_text = StringVar(value="Не выбран")
```

Comment: У вас переменная btn_text ни к какому элементу управления не привязана, как вы вообще определили, что она не меняется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. При привязке обработчиков нажатия к кнопкам нужно убрать скобки, иначе функции-обработчики выполнятся один раз при запуске программы, в параметр command передастся результат выполнения этих функций (`None`), из-за этого при нажатии на кнопки ничего не будет происходить.
2. У вас переменная ни к какому контролу не привязана, поэтому визуально ничего не меняется, хотя значение переменной будет меняться (если поправить п.1, конечно же).
3. Если переменная не перезаписывается, а вызываются методы от объекта в этой переменной, то `global` не нужно.

Ниже пример, где я добавил `Label`, к которому привязал переменную `btn_text`. При нажатии на кнопки текст в `label` меняется меняется:

```
from tkinter import *

#Главное окно
main = Tk()
main.title("Умное Рассписание:Тест")
main.geometry("1100x650")
main.resizable(False, False)
# main.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', close)
main["bg"] = "#F0F8FF"

#Переменная через которую происходит изменения
btn_text = StringVar(value="Не выбран")

# Добавлено: метка, к которой привязана переменная,
# в ней будет меняться текст при нажатии на кнопки
Label(main, textvariable=btn_text).pack()

#Функции, которые должны менять
def choice_clicked_1():
    btn_text.set("Русский язык")
def choice_clicked_2():
    btn_text.set("Английский язык")
def choice_clicked_3():
    btn_text.set("Алгебра")
def choice_clicked_4():
    btn_text.set("Геометрия")


btn1 = Button(main, text="Русский язык", bg="#F0F8FF", command=choice_clicked_1)
btn1.pack()
btn2 = Button(main, text="Английский язык", bg="#F0F8FF", command=choice_clicked_2)
btn2.pack()
btn3 = Button(main, text="Алгебра", bg="#F0F8FF", command=choice_clicked_3)
btn3.pack()
btn4 = Button(main, text="Геометрия", bg="#F0F8FF", command=choice_clicked_4)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо, это я глупый, в коде есть переменная, которая меняется в зависимости от нажатия по кнопке, просто я её добавить забыл

Comment: Если вам не сложно, не могли бы вы ещё ответить на этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240494/Закрытие-toplevel-закрывает-и-основное-окно-tkinter

Answer (score 0):

`global btn_text` надо писать в начале каждой функции где эта переменная будет использоваться

```
def choice_clicked_1():
    global btn_text
    bn_text.set("Русский язык")
```

также место

```
command=choice_clicked_1()
```

надо писать

```
command=choice_clicked_1
```

Comment: не сработало, всё ещё ничего не изменяется.